# Pandas merge a list in a dataframe column with another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes:

```
ID   LIST_VALUES
 1     [a,b,c]
 2     [a,n,t]
 3     [x]
 4     [h,h]


VALUE     MAPPING
 a         alpha
 b         bravo
 c         charlie
 n         november
 h         hotel
 t         tango
 x         xray
```

I need to add a new column to the first dataframe that shows the VALUES from  the second dataframe based on what is in the LIST_VALUES list. If a value is duplicated in LIST_VALUES, only show it once in the output. So:

```
ID   LIST_VALUES    new_col
 1     [a,b,c]       alpha,bravo,charlie
 2     [a,n,t]       alpha,november,tango
 3     [x]           xray
 4     [h,h]         hotel
```

I have tried to merge `pd.merge` but I keep getting stuck as I cannot merge with elements in a list.

```
df_new = df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on='LIST_VALUES', right_on='VALUES')
```

This will only work where a LIST_VALUE has only 1 element so in this example ID 3. I need it to work where there are multiple values in a list.

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension with map by `Series` same way like dictionary, last remove duplicated values by `dict.fromkeys` trick and `join` values together:

```
d = df2.set_index('VALUE')['MAPPING']
df1['new_col'] = [', '.join(dict.fromkeys([d[y] for y in x if y in d]).keys()) 
                                                               for x in df1['LIST_VALUES']]

print (df1)
   ID LIST_VALUES                 new_col
0   1   [a, b, c]   alpha, bravo, charlie
1   2   [a, n, t]  alpha, november, tango
2   3         [x]                    xray
3   4      [h, h]                   hotel
```

If order is not important of new values is possible use `set` for remove duplicates:

```
d = df2.set_index('VALUE')['MAPPING']
df1['new_col'] = [', '.join(set([d[y] for y in x if y in d])) for x in df1['LIST_VALUES']]

print (df1)
   ID LIST_VALUES                 new_col
0   1   [a, b, c]   alpha, charlie, bravo
1   2   [a, n, t]  alpha, tango, november
2   3         [x]                    xray
3   4      [h, h]                   hotel
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to build a dictionary from your second dataframe using [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html). Then use a nested list comprehension to lookup the dictionary using the values in the lists:

```
d = df2.set_index('VALUE').MAPPING.to_dict()
# {'a': 'alpha', 'b': 'bravo', 'c': 'charlie', ...

df['new_col'] = [','.join([d[j] for j in i]) for i in df.LIST_VALUES]

print(df)

 ID LIST_VALUES                new_col
0   1   [a, b, c]   alpha,bravo,charlie
1   2   [a, b, c]   alpha,bravo,charlie
2   3         [x]                  xray
3   4      [h, h]           hotel,hotel
```

Setup:

```
print(df2)

 VALUE   MAPPING
0     a     alpha
1     b     bravo
2     c   charlie
3     n  november
4     h     hotel
5     t     tango
6     x      xray

print(df)

   ID LIST_VALUES
0   1   [a, b, c]
1   2   [a, b, c]
2   3         [x]
3   4      [h, h]
```