# Pyspark/SQL join a column having list values to another dataframe column

Tags: sql, list, join, pyspark

I want to join two tables the way it is asked here, [Pandas merge a list in a dataframe column with another dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60756658/pandas-merge-a-list-in-a-dataframe-column-with-another-dataframe)

```
# Input Data Frame 
ID   LIST_VALUES
 1     [a,b,c]
 2     [a,n,t]
 3     [x]
 4     [h,h]


VALUE     MAPPING
 a         alpha
 b         bravo
 c         charlie
 n         november
 h         hotel
 t         tango
 x         xray
```

I want the following output, How do I do this in pyspark or in SQL?

```
# EXPECTED OUTPUT DATAFRAME

ID   LIST_VALUES    new_col
 1     [a,b,c]       alpha,bravo,charlie
 2     [a,n,t]       alpha,november,tango
 3     [x]           xray
 4     [h,h]         hotel
```

Comment: links/images are not helpful when reproducing a question in the end users system, consider reading [how to make a good reproducible pyspark example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples) and edit your question according;y

Comment: Noted, thanks for the edit! @anky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created the following data and output based on the provided link

the program with *pyspark DataFrame API* would like the following:

```
    # imports 
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

# replicating the data

cols = ['ID','LIST_VALUES']
row_1 = [1,['a','b','c']]
row_2 = [2,['a','n','t']]
row_3 = [3,['x']]
row_4 = [4, ['h','h']]
rows = [row_1, row_2,row_3,row_4]

df_1 = spark.createDataFrame(rows, cols)

cols = ['VALUE','MAPPING']
row_1 = ['a','alpha']
row_2 = ['b', 'bravo']
row_3 = ['c', 'charlie']
row_4 = ['n', 'november']
row_5 = ['h', 'hotel']
row_6 = ['t', 'tango']
row_7 = ['x', 'xray']

rows = [row_1, row_2,row_3,row_4, row_5, row_6, row_7]

df_a = spark.createDataFrame(rows, cols)

# we need to explode the LIST_VALUES Column first
df_1 = df_1.withColumn("EXP_LIST_VALUES",F.explode(F.col('LIST_VALUES')))
df_2 = df_1.select('ID','EXP_LIST_VALUES')

# then we can do a left join with df_2 and df_a

df_new = df_a.join(df_2,df_a.VALUE == df_2.EXP_LIST_VALUES,'left')

# applying a window functions 

df_output = df_new.select(F.col('ID'),
           F.collect_set(F.col('VALUE')).over(Window.partitionBy(F.col('ID'))).alias('LIST_VALUES'), \F.array_join(F.collect_set(F.col('MAPPING')).over(Window.partitionBy(F.col('ID'))),',').alias('new_col')).dropDuplicates()


display(df_output)
```

The output looks like the following dataframe

```
# +---+-----------+--------------------+
# | ID|LIST_VALUES|             new_col|
# +---+-----------+--------------------+
# |  1|[c, b, a]  | bravo,charlie,alpha|
# |  2|[t, n, a]  |november,tango,alpha|
# |  3|      [x]  |                xray|
# |  4|      [h]  |               hotel|
# +---+-----------+--------------------|
```

Comment: Thanks alot for this solution, I am very new to pyspark so this has been of immense help!

Comment: if this works for you, you can upvote the answer.